# spring boot: ignoring the Elasticsearch configuration and ends up with exception org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am not able to create the `bean` of an `ElasticsearchRepository` using `@Autowired`. I am taking this [link as a reference](https://dzone.com/articles/first-step-spring-boot-and) in my code to enable elastic search capabilities with spring boot. I think my code is ignoring the `Elasticsearch configuration`.

platform details:

```
Operating system: Windows 10
Java: 1.8.0.77 build
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4
```

Exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.PostRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

In project POM

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.191</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`Elasticsearch configuration`

```
package config;

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:config/elasticsearch.properties")
    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "repository")
    @Service("searchConfiguration")
    public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {
        @Resource
        private Environment environment;
        @Bean
        public Client client() {
            TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
            TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port")));
            client.addTransportAddress(address);
            return client;
        }

        @Bean
        ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
            return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
        }
    }
```

**application properties file**

```
elasticsearch.host = localhost
 # if you use you local elasticsearch host
elasticsearch.port = 9300
```

**Data mapping object:**

```
package core;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

import java.util.UUID;


@Document(indexName = "explore", type = "explore", shards = 1, replicas = 0)
public class FileProperties {

    String id= UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    String filename;

    public String getSize(long length) {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }



    public String getPath(String absolutePath) {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getMimeType() {
        return mimeType;
    }

    public void setMimeType(String mimeType) {
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    String size;
    String path;
    String mimeType;

}
```

**Repository: we extends from ElasticsearchRepository**

```
package repository;

import core.FileProperties;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service("elasticsearchRepository")
public interface PostRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<FileProperties, String> {

    Page<FileProperties> findByTagsName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Data access service**

```
public interface FilePropertiesService  {
    FileProperties save(FileProperties fileProperties);
    FileProperties findOne(String id);
    Iterable<FileProperties> findAll();

package core;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import repository.PostRepository;



@Service("filePropertiesServiceIMPL")
public class FilePropertiesServiceIMPL  implements FilePropertiesService {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private PostRepository elasticsearchRepository;

    @Override
    public FileProperties save(FileProperties fileProperties) {
       return elasticsearchRepository.save(fileProperties);
    }

    @Override
    public FileProperties findOne(String id) {
        return elasticsearchRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<FileProperties> findAll() {
        return  elasticsearchRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Testing and the result**

```
package core;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;


@Slf4j
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppStart  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    public FileSystem exploreFileSystem;



    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppStart.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void listen() {
        exploreFileSystem.LetsExploreFileSystem();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AppStart.class, args);

    }
}
```

Result:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.PostRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

If the repositories are not in the same or in a subpackage as the class with the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`, you have to specify the following annotation with the package of the repositories as attribute:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository")
```

on your AppStart class. 
By default, Spring will only scan the package and subpackages of your main application class.